# IE connection setting: Automatic configuration vs. manual proxy server - precedence?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

When I choose `Use automatic configuration script` and point it to our proxies pac-file, will the proxy setting on the bottom become inactive?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you check "Automatically detect settings" and "Use automatic configuration script", the automatic configuration will take precedence over the manual settings.

So, the short answer to your question is: Yes

Regards